# Why can't my computer and Android phone communicate over WiFi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, android, lan

I am trying to run an internet radio server on my computer with icecast that I will connect to over the LAN with my phone using VLC player, however on my network my computer cannot ping my phone and my phone cannot access my icecast server. I have also tested running an Apache web server on my computer but my phone cannot access that either. I can access other devices on my LAN from my computer, though.

I have changed all of the wifi settings in my phone such that it does not sleep when powered off, and it is connected to the network just fine--it has on problem accessing web pages and it shows that it is connected to the same wifi network (which is also the only available wifi network).

Why are my phone and computer not able to connect with or ping each other?

My phone is an HTC One running Android and my computer is an old Lenovo laptop running Debian.

**EDIT:** I think there is some sort of firewall running on my phone but I do not know what it is or how to turn it off, and my theory is that it only blocks traffic on unencrypted networks. This is my guess because the icecast server setup worked fine on an encrypted network but it is not working on this unencrypted network. I have Avast mobile security installed in addition to Lookout Mobile but Avast says that I have to root my device in order to use the firewall feature so I doubt it is that, and Lookout mobile does not have a firewall feature that I can find.

Comment: Check your firewall. It may block any connection from outside the machine. Also check if both devices are not isolated by your wireless router.

Comment: I can connect to lots of other devices on the network though l, like a secondary laptop or even other android phones that are visible. I don't think it is a firewall, and I don't know why only those two devices would be specifically isolated.

Comment: Just from your laptop or also from your phone? Again check your firewall. If in doubt, just add an exclusion for icecast.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no firewall set up on the network or on the phone that would be blocking connections, and the connection between laptop and phone have worked on other networks.